# how can I observe async events in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech

Hope I can explain this correctly, I'd like to see how asynchronous events like TTS/execute line up with other events. Is there a way to see the timeline in e.g. the Android Studio debugger ?

In this concrete case, I'm trying to understand when TTs/onInit happens wrt. the `mPager.post(new Runnable())` event I have in my ViewPager.

Probably totally impossible or improbable but hey, never hurts to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I **assume** you are facing problems using breakpoints on asynchronous code. If that is your question then you you can add this line to your async code:

```
Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

**before** your breakpoint (i.e. as first line in `doInBackground()`).

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html

Comment: well, actually, I was trying to see why my TTS doesn't work in certain cases and I suspect that onInit wasn't done yet, while my other code ran. Tried something stupid like ``while() {}`` and of course it hung, so I just wondered if there is something like a visual timeline that shows when async events kick in. Probably just a wild goose chase. Obviously, I need to go back and read some books to understand the underlying process etc.